# Replacing multiple consecutive spaces with Pipe character

Tags: string, regular-expressions

I need to replace multiple consecutive spaces with pipe character ,I tried various regular expression but i couldn't get the output .Can anyone give me solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = ' this is a    multiple spaces sample   ';
System.debug(s.replaceAll('\\s+','|'));
```

gives you this result: `DEBUG||this|is|a|multiple|spaces|sample|`

To replace ONLY when you have more than one space use this:

```
System.debug(s.replaceAll('[ ]{2,}','|'));
```

this returns :

```
DEBUG| this is a|multiple spaces sample|
12:08:18.174 (37342000)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
```

Comment: I tried this long back ...I need to remove only multiple consecutive spaces with a pipe character ...not the single space i.e. 'this is a|multiple spaces sample'

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: It worked ...thank you.Can you give me some links to study about how to create regular expressions if u can..

Comment: Uff, That is a really tough and large topic, start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: i want one more help from you...I need to replace all special characters except those between strings o tried this [^\\w\'] ..but it  is replacing special characters between the quotes

Comment: You should make a new question for that. Add as many samples as you can